# jQuery wrapAll / unwrap messes up positioning

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, wrapall

After wrapping divs with jQuery, unwrapping them and then trying to wrap them again seems to lose float property (my guess) and I can not figure out how to fix this.

When pushing wrap button in the JSFiddle bellow for the first time, it aligns divs like I expect it to do. Then I unwrap divs and it puts them back to original position which is fine too. But then when I wrap again, divs go one under another instead of a square formation. Any ideas what is wrong?

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/skunksts/h9ftL/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a1" class="block">A1</div>
    <div id="a2" class="block">A2</div>
    <div id="b1" class="block">B1</div>
    <div id="b2" class="block">B2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="wrapIt()">wrap</button>
<button onclick="unwrapIt()">unwrap</button>
```

CSS - 
See in JSFiddle. It just sets positioning for container, four divs in it, and wrapping.

JS

```
function wrapIt(){
    $(".block").wrapAll("<div id='wrapping'></div>")
    $(".block").css({ 'position': 'relative' })
    $(".block").css({ 'display': 'inline-block' })
    $(".block").css({ 'margin': 10 }) 
    $(".block").css({"float": "left"})
}
function unwrapIt(){
    $(".block").unwrap()
    $(".block").css({ 'position': 'absolute' })
    $(".block").css({ 'margin': 0 }) 
    $(".block").css({"clear": "both"})

    $("#a1").css({"margin-top": 30})
    $("#a1").css({"margin-left": 30})
    $("#a2").css({"margin-top": 30})
    $("#a2").css({"margin-left": 80})
    $("#b1").css({"margin-top": 80})
    $("#b1").css({"margin-left": 30})
    $("#b2").css({"margin-top": 80})
    $("#b2").css({"margin-left": 80})    
}
```

Comment: jQuery css takes an array or you can nest you calls. Just for improvement of that code

Comment: And you could use "margin: top right bottom left" syntax.

Comment: This is a simplified version of the actual code. Any ideas why wrapping does not work like expected?

Comment: why you have used " " and ' ' both in jquery. even `;` is missing from every line.
and if you are creating a block for css in jquery then why you defining all the classes again & again.

Comment: I use JSFiddle for fast prototyping - hence both " and '. Just a mistake. There is a long discussion on why you need or do not need ;. So this is a prefference. Regarding classes - I just used copy paste to be fast - I am learning programming only for 2 months now. Anyway, thank you all for correcting these issues.But does anybody know how to fix the problem the question was about?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone searches for similar solution: I did solve the problem in a slightly different way - I used addClass and removeClass for this. (Still no clue why the first one did not work...)

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/skunksts/hHyqU/7/)

Here is the code:

HTML
The same as above

CSS

```
.wrappedclass {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.unwrappedclass {
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;

}

.block {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: grey;

}
#container {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#wrapping {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".block").addClass("unwrappedclass")
     $("#a1").css({"margin": "30px 0 0 30px"})
     $("#a2").css({"margin": "30px 0 0 80px"})
     $("#b1").css({"margin": "80px 0 0 30px"})
     $("#b2").css({"margin": "80px 0 0 80px"})
})

function wrapIt(){
    $(".block").wrapAll("<div id='wrapping'></div>")
               .removeClass("unwrappedclass")
               .addClass("wrappedclass")
    wrappedFormation()
}

function unwrapIt(){
    $(".block").unwrap()
               .removeClass("wrappedclass")
               .addClass("unwrappedclass")    
    unwrappedFormation()
}

function unwrappedFormation(){
    $("#a1").css({"margin": "30px 0 0 30px"})
    $("#a2").css({"margin": "30px 0 0 80px"})
    $("#b1").css({"margin": "80px 0 0 30px"})
    $("#b2").css({"margin": "80px 0 0 80px"})      
}

function wrappedFormation(){
    $(".block").css({"margin": "17px"})
}
```